# Django making instance of class in two different views does not function

Tags: python, django, class

Im trying to create an instance of a class i made called Alert, so i can show alerts in my template by looping through each instance i created.

So i have a simple Alert class like this:

**Alert Class:**

```py
class Alert():
    def __init__(self,level, content):
        self.level = level
        self.content = content
```

I have a model of Employees to show some data about them.

**Model Employee:**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,to_field = 'username', on_delete = models.CASCADE,null = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 255)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
        unique_together = ['name','owner']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have two views like the following:

**View Add Employee:**

```py
@login_required(redirect_field_name = '/login',login_url='/login')
def add_employee(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            name = request.POST['name']

            query = Employee(name = name,owner = request.user)
            query.save()

            return redirect("main:somepage")

        except:
            instance = Alert(level = 'error',content = 'This username is already exist in your employee list!')
            return redirect("main:somepage")
```

And this is my second View:

**View Delete Employee:**

```py
@login_required(redirect_field_name = '/login',login_url='/login')
def delete_employee(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        query = Employee.objects.filter(owner = request.user,name = request.POST['name'])

        if len(query) == 1:
            query.delete()

        instance2 = Alert(level='success', content='Successfully Deleted!')
        return redirect("main:main_manage")
```

Now those views are being called once in my template user requests to add or to delete obviously.

Above Those two, i have a general view employees view also,
**This is the view of the page i redirect to "main:somepage"**

Here is how it looks.

**Render Employees Page:**

```py
@login_required(redirect_field_name = '/login',login_url='/login')
def view_employees(request):
    employees = Employee.objects.filter(owner = request.user)
    alerts = get_all_instances(Alert)

    return render(request, template_name=r'main/manage.html',context = {'employees': employees,
                                                                        'alerts': alerts})
```

Unfortunately what happens is, **Add Employee exception** Alert instance is working fine and showing the Alert instance when i redirect.
But nothing happens when i do the same steps in the **Delete Employee** view.

And i could not figure out why.
There are two instances created in two different views, and one of them is kept in the Alert instances and the other one is not.

This is the most important, here is how my **get_all_instances** function looks like:

```py
import gc

def get_all_instances(of_class):
    _instances = []
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
         if isinstance(obj,of_class):
             _instances.append(obj)

    return _instances
```

I tried to debug and figure out what could be the difference but i did not come up with any idea.

Any help would be appreciated.

Dont believe its necessary but here is my code templates page of the employees:

```html
    <section id="main-content"> <!--main section start -->
      <section class="wrapper">

      <!--Display Alerts only if required start -->
      {% for alert in alerts %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class = col-lg-10>
                <div class="alert alert-block fade in">
                    <strong>There is an alert! </strong>{{ alert.content }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}

      <!--Display Alerts only if required end-->
```

Comment: may be this condition "if len(query) == 1" is not satisfying. check if query exist.

Comment: well i looked into it now and erased the condition.
What happened is the delete occured, but the alert still did not pop up